# Safari monospaced font doesn't support Cyrillic?

Tags: macos, safari, font

To my surpise, it seems the default Safari monospaced font (that is, if you have `font-family: monospace` for your HTML) doesn't support Cyrillic letters. What font does it use? (It seems it is SF Mono, right? But SF Mono, if used in TextEdit and Xcode, *does* support Cyrillic!) Or maybe this is a bug?

As you can see, the style of Latin and Cyrillic characters is very different:

[image]

```
The same text in raw HTML, so that you can test it yourself:

<pre>woodes rogers
a cruising voyage round the world

фёдор каржавин
краткое известие о достопамятных приключениях капитана д'севиля</pre>
```

Sonoma 14.1.1, Safari 17.1

---

later edit: **Guys, do you have the same issue at least? Feedback is welcome!**

Comment: This is what I see - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiY24.png - it's all rendered in Menlo